# Eigenvalues of a specific matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, block-matrices

I have a block matrix

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
    I_0&        I_1&        \cdots&     I_1\\
    I_2&        I_0&        \ddots&     \vdots\\
    \vdots&     \ddots&     \ddots&     I_1\\
    I_2&        \cdots&     I_2&        I_0\\
\end{bmatrix}_{n \times n}$$

with

$$I_0=\begin{bmatrix}
    0&      1\\
    1&      0\\
\end{bmatrix}, \qquad
I_1=\begin{bmatrix}
    0&      1\\
    -1&     0\\
\end{bmatrix},\qquad
I_2=\begin{bmatrix}
    0&      -1\\
    1&      0\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

I want to find all its eigenvalues $\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_{2n}\}$, where $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2 < \cdots < \lambda_{2n}$.

Due to the chiral symmetry, we can find $\lambda_i=-\lambda_{2n+1-i}$ for all $i$.

Comment: I don't know about the chiral symmetry. But $I_0^2=I$, $I_1^2=-I$, and $I_0I_1+I_1I_0=0$ (where $I$ is the $2\times2$ identity matrix) imply $M^2=-(n-2)E$, where $E_{i,j}=I$ for all $i,j$. Hence $M^2/(-n(n-2))$ is an orthogonal projection of rank $2$. This means that the nonzero eigenvalues of $M^2$ is only $-n(n-2)$ with multiplicity $2$. The nonzero eigenvalues of $M$ are simple and $\pm i\sqrt{n(n-2)}$ (because the trace is zero).

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA I am so sorry. I ignore an important property, i.e., M=M^T.

Comment: It can be shown that finding the eigenvalues of $M$ is equivalent to finding those of $A$ or $A^2$ where $A$ is the matrix with a zero diagonal and entries $a_{i,j}=1$ for $j>i$; $a_{i,j}=-1$ for $i>j$. If you try with $n$   you see the eigenvalues (for $A$ and $M$) gets complicated with radicals in terms of (large) $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the signed circulant matrix
$$U:=\left[\begin{matrix}
 & 1 & & &  \\ 
 & &  \ddots & & \\
 & &  & 1 &\\
 -1 &  & & & 
\end{matrix}\right]
\mbox{ in }
M_n(\mathbb{C}),$$
one has
$$M= 1 \otimes I_0 +  (U+U^2+ \cdots + U^{n-1}) \otimes I_1
\mbox{ in }
M_n(\mathbb{C})\otimes M_2(\mathbb{C}).$$
For $\omega:=\exp\frac{i\pi}{n}$,
the unitary matrix $U$ has eigenvalues
$\{ \omega^k : k=1,3,5,\ldots,2n-1\}$
and eigenvectors
$v_k:=[\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & \omega^k & \omega^{2k} & \cdots &\omega^{(n-1)k}\end{smallmatrix}]^{\mathrm{T}}/\sqrt{n}$ in $\ell_2^n$.
Accordingly, the matrix $M$ is decomposed into the direct sum of
$$I_0+ (\omega^k+\omega^{2k}+ \cdots + \omega^{(n-1)k})I_1 
=\left[\begin{matrix}
  0 & \lambda_k\\
  \overline{\lambda_k} & 0
 \end{matrix}\right]
\mbox{ acting on }
\mathbb{C}v_k \otimes \ell_2^2,$$
where
$$\lambda_k=\frac{2}{1-\omega^k}.$$
The eigenvalues of $M$ are
$\pm|\lambda_k|$,  $k=1,3,\ldots,2(n-1)$
with eigenvectors
$ v_k \otimes 
[\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & \pm \mathrm{sgn}(\overline{\lambda_k}) \end{smallmatrix}]^{\mathrm{T}}/\sqrt{2}$ in $\ell_2^n \otimes \ell_2^n$.
Note that since $|\lambda_k|=|\lambda_{2n-k}|$, all eigenvalues
except for $1$ (corresponding to the case when $n$ is odd and $\lambda_n=-1$) have multiplicity $2$.

Comment: I have two questions. 1. Can we use the method to solve the eigenvalues of any Toeplitz matrices? 2. Can we solve its eigenstates?

Comment: I revised my answer to include eigenvectors. The answer to your question 1 is negative. There is no general methods of calculating eigenvalues of a general (hermitian) Toeplitz matrices (and there is a lot of research on this topics).

Comment: I understand. If the diagonal terms (i.e., I_0) are not identical, is the method is ineffective? Here, I_0, I_1, and I_2 can be regarded as the numbers.